# Taskgated process not running

Tags: big-sur

I am running mac os Big Sur.

While sign-coding gdb, I killed taskgated via activity monitor expecting system to restart it. It's one day since then and taskgated is still not running.

I checked in activity monitor and terminal ps command as well, but taskgated is not running.

I even re started my MBP, but still same result.

How can I start taskgated now?